# Computing the residue of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have the following contour integral (with C the positively oriented unit circle centered at the origin):

$$
\frac{-i}{4}\int_{C}\frac{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}{z\left(-z^4+3z^2-1\right)}dz
$$

It has isolated singularities inside $C$ at $z = 0, \pm\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$

$z = 0$ is a simple pole and the residue at that point is easily computed. I am unsure how to compute the residues at $z = \pm\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$, without having to write the Laurent series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ of order $m$, you can use the formula
$$Res(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!} \lim_{z\to z_0} [(z-z_0)^m \cdot f(z)]^{(m-1)}$$

where $g^{(n)}$ means the $n$-th derivative of $g$.

Please ask if you need work on how that formula is obtained.

Comment: sorry, I can't see the difference
actually, $f^{(n)}$ means the $n$-th derivative.
I'll explain it anyway, thanks.

Comment: I am familiar with that formula, however I don't see a way to factor the denominator in such a way that the order is the power of $(z-z_0)$. (I might be missing something obvious)

Comment: @Tom The notation $f^{(n)}$ is pretty standard for the $n$th derivative of $f$.

Comment: @user405561 you can solve the equation $-z^4+3z^2-1$ by substituting $t=z^2$.

Comment: Indeed, that's how I arrived at $$z0 = \pm\srqt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$, I still don't know $m$, though.

Comment: Then, the equation $-z^4+3z^2-1$ has four roots, $\pm\sqrt\frac{3\pm\sqrt5}{2}$, so each one has order $1$.

Comment: The other two are ignored because they are outside the contour

Comment: Yes, but then the order of the pole has to be $1$. Your polynomial can be written (except for a constant)
$$\left(z-\sqrt\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(z-\sqrt\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(z+\sqrt\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(z+\sqrt\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Oh wow, it was right in my face. (－‸ლ).